# Output buffering in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

While working with PHP I used output buffer as a way to "combine" multiple method outputs and ex. write buffet to a file.

Example:

```
ob_start();
print $foo->bar();
print $anotherFoo->anotherBar();
$output= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
file_put_contents("output.html",$output);
```

Is there an equivalent in C#?

Comment: Are you wanting this for WebForms or for MVC?

Comment: Sorry that's for MVC.

Comment: What you want to do is first write the output to a string. Then you can write that string to a file, which is trivial. The trick is getting the string in the first place. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string